# Duplicate CDN cancel features

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, cdn

I'm trying to use Bootstrap-collapse like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible&stacked=h) but it didn't fully work (the text doesn't collapse back after 2nd click).

I tried to remove one of the loacl CDN scripts and than it works.
(The row is marked)

I dowloaded the 'datatable' from [this site](https://datatables.net/), because I wanted to translate the "search" to my language.
With the regular CDN it works great.

Why it's happening?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <!--The problem row-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/datatables.js"></script>


   <!-- jQuery -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 

    <!-- Bootstrap -->

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Toggle -->
     <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>



</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Datatables [Internationalisation plug-in](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/) for translation. On initialisation pass the url of either the Translations cdn bellow the example or download it and customize it to your needs.